# I have a intel AC 8260 and cant find the drivers

Tags: drivers, nic

Hi I bought this part https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.com/1200Mbps-Ubit-Bluetooth-Dual-Band-PC-Shipped/dp/B07JNMZWZL&ved=2ahUKEwj-hpDGur_jAhVNvFkKHaouBdoQFjABegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw0bG21LzzwlQT6GFySZQtE8 
And I cant find the AC 2860 drivers for ubuntu, if anyone can help I'd appreciate it!!

Comment: Intel WiFi cards usually don't need drivers. Why do you think this one needs?

Comment: I thought all hard ware components need drivers

Comment: They do but most are already included = natively supported. Again, what's wrong with yours?

Comment: No native support......

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: The reason for the above question is, as you can see in the table in the answer below, **AC8260 has been supported since kernel 4.1**. Any currently supported Ubuntu release is running kernels much newer than that so, if your isn't working out of the box, youŕe probably using an End of Life Ubuntu release and 1. you shouldn't because those no longer receive security updates, you should upgrade to or install a supported release and 2. that alone makes your question off-topic as we don't support EoL releases for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel Wifi drivers are built into the Linux kernel already. To see them use:

```
lsmod | grep iwlwifi
```

Firmware for Linux Intel WiFi drivers by card model and Kernel version are [here](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html):

[image: Linux Wifi Firmware.png]

For general questions about Intel Wi-Fi on Linux, email linuxwifi@intel.com.